# Integration Tests With Topshelf to Start a C# Windows Service

Tags: c#, unit-testing, windows-services, integration-testing, topshelf

I'm using [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) to host a Windows Service written in C# and I now want to write some integration tests. My initialisation code is held in a launcher class like the following:

```
public class Launcher
{
    private Host host;

    /// <summary>
    /// Configure and launch the windows service
    /// </summary>
    public void Launch()
    {
        //Setup log4net from config file
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(DEFAULT_CONFIG));

        //Setup Ninject dependency injection
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel(new MyModule());

        this.host = HostFactory.New(x =>
        {
            x.SetServiceName("MyService");
            x.SetDisplayName("MyService");
            x.SetDescription("MyService");

            x.RunAsLocalSystem();
            x.StartAutomatically();

            x.Service<MyWinService>(s =>
            {
                s.ConstructUsing(() => kernel.Get<MyWinService>());
                s.WhenStarted(w => w.Start());
                s.WhenStopped(w => w.Stop());
            });
        });

        this.host.Run(); //code blocks here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dispose the service host
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.host != null && this.host is IDisposable)
        {
            (this.host as IDisposable).Dispose();
            this.host = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write some integration tests to make sure that log4net and Ninject get set up properly and Topshelf launches my service. The problem is, once you call `Run()` on the Topshelf host, the code just blocks so my test code never gets run.

I thought of calling `Launch()` in a separate thread in the `SetUp` section of my tests but then I need a bit of a hack to put in a `Thread.Sleep(1000)` to make sure the tests don't run before `Launch()` has finished. I can't use a proper sync on it (like a `ManualResetEvent`) because the `Launch()` never returns. The current code is:

```
private Launcher launcher;
private Thread launchThread;

[TestFixtureSetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    launcher = new Launcher();
    launchThread = new Thread(o => launcher.Launch());
    launchThread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(2500); //yuck!!
}

[TestFixtureTearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    if (launcher != null)
    {
        launcher.Dispose(); //ouch
    }
}
```

Ideally what I'm looking for is a non-blocking way of launching the service and a programmatic way of stopping it again to put in my `TearDown`. At the moment my `TearDown` just disposes the launcher (so the `TearDown` literally tears it down!).

Does anyone have experience in testing Topshelf services in this way? I can do the above relatively easily using the standard `ServiceHost` but I much prefer the explicit configuration and ease of installation in Topshelf.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/blob/v2.3/src/Topshelf/Config/Builders/RunBuilder.cs#L113 I think is what you want. `AfterStartingService` could be used to set a `ManualResetEvent` from a different thread.

Now this is might work out for you, but this feels like overly complicated and could be validated just by deploying to dev/staging and doing smoke tests to your system. However, without more understanding of your environment, that might not be possible.

Comment: @SteveC not anymore. The link is accessible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and I chose to isolate the service instanciation and interaction from the actual Topshelf hosting (which consists of nothing more than resolving your service using Ninject in your case).

Adam Rodger has a fair point and after having a quick look to the Run method for the `ConsoleRunHost`, it will actually hang to wait for a `ManualResetEvent` and won't give you the control back until the service terminates.

At your place, to code your smoke/regression tests, just get the kernel and the module into your `SetUp` method, resolve the service, do your tests and dispose it in the `TearDown`